# Incremental Backup with 7-Zip in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, 7zip

I'm working on a Backup-Tool in PowerShell and now I want to create an incremental Backup but I don't know how.

I already have the code for a full backup (which is quite easy). Now I want to create an incremental Backup. What is the best way to do that with 7-Zip? Is there a way to compare the file's hashcodes in the old, already zipped backup with the new one?

This is the code for my full backup:

```
if ($backupType -eq "v") {
    # Copy Files with Robocopy
    robocopy $sourcePath $destinationPath /E
    
    # Ask user for password
    $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Geben Sie ein Passwort zum Verschlüsseln des Backups ein"
    
    # Create a 7-Zip Archive
    $arguments = "a -tzip `"$destinationPath\backup.zip`" `"$sourcePath\*`" -p$password"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
    
    # Generate a Logfile
    robocopy $destinationPath $logPath /L /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /NP /BYTES /XJ /R:0 /W:0 > $logPath
}
```

Comment: Just figured out how it works, hope you can see it now :)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1630026/730625), 7-zip only includes CRC32 hashes which are not sufficient to compare file content. What you could do instead is include a file in the archive that contains SHA-256 hash values and file paths. This should be added as the first file to the archive in case you create solid archives (because solid archives require to extract everything before the file you are interested in). Then you only need to extract the hash file and compare with hashes of the files on disk to determine what has changed.